# Button is Clicking Before File Upload is Complete in Webbrowser C#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

On a Windows Form, I am using a Webbrowser control in C#. It's job is to upload a file and then press the submit button. My only problem is that my code tries to press the submit button before the file is finished uploading. I tried using:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

In between the two tasks (commented out below). This seems to pause the entire process so that didn't work. Can anyone tell me what the best way to do this is?

```
private void imageBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    this.imageBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= imageBrowser_DocumentCompleted;

    Populate().ContinueWith((_) =>
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("Form populated!");
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

    try
    {
        var buttons = imageBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");

        foreach (HtmlElement button in buttons)
        {
            if (button.InnerText == "done")
            {
                button.InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //debug
    }

}

async Task Populate()
{
    var elements = imageBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
    foreach (HtmlElement file in elements)
    {
        if (file.GetAttribute("name") == "file")
        {
            file.Focus();
            await PopulateInputFile(file);
        }
    }
}

async Task PopulateInputFile(HtmlElement file)
{
    file.Focus();
    // delay the execution of SendKey to let the Choose File dialog show up
    var sendKeyTask = Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith((_) =>
    {
        // this gets executed when the dialog is visible
        SendKeys.Send("C:\\Users\\00I0I_c0OlVXtE6FO_600x450.jpg" + "{ENTER}");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");

    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    file.InvokeMember("Click"); // this shows up the dialog

    await sendKeyTask;

    // delay continuation to let the Choose File dialog hide
    await Task.Delay(500);
    //SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");

}
```

Comment: Can I just ask, is the `WebBrowser` control there solely to automate the file upload? If so, and you're using .NET 4.5, you might want to look at the [WebClient.UploadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which will allow you to do it without all the messy automation. If you're using an older version of .NET you can still do it with a `HttpWebRequest`, although it's slightly more complicated. Still simpler than automation though!

Comment: Vigs, can you tell us more about the website you're trying to automate? In "oldschool" HTML, the upload of "file" form fields occurs when you submit the entire form (upload starts when Submit is clicked). Does your page have some advanced file upload functionality (JavaScript, AJAX, etc.) where uploads occur asynchronously, and only at a later point in time you click Submit (no upload starts on Submit)?

Answer (score 0):

Is the `WebBrowser` loading a local file? Can you post the [html](/questions/tagged/html) code as well?

I came across such a situation when I was working with [[image]google-maps-api-3](/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3). I was setting some markers on the form in the `WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted` but was getting a null object exception. So I moved the code for set marker to a .NET `Button` control. I noticed that the exception was not thrown when I set the marker after the map tiles completed loading. `DocumentCompleted` was firing before the tiles got loaded and I was getting a null object exception.

So what I did was to use a `tilesLoaded` event in my [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript). In this event, I set a property back in C# code which set the markers in the `OnPropertyChanged` event.

I know what I am posting here is not a solution. But if you post your [html](/questions/tagged/html) code, I can give you answer with some code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. The code I was using to click the button was in the wrong spot. The code now looks like so:

```
private void imageBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    this.imageBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= imageBrowser_DocumentCompleted;

    try
    {
        Populate().ContinueWith((_) =>
        {
            var buttons = imageBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");

            foreach (HtmlElement button in buttons)
            {
                if (button.InnerText == "done")
                {
                button.InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    }
    catch
    {
        //debug
    }

}
```

My mistake was thinking in terms of having a certain amount of seconds pass before executed the next line of code, when I should have been thinking in terms of having the next line of code execute when the previous task was complete.